# Read a txt file per line into an array and dir each entry in the array

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

I'm currently trying to use cmd to read a batch file which I've created with PowerShell.  Each line within this file is a directory so I want to be able to create a loop which will read each line; dir the directory and store the output within a textfile.

My idea on how to do this so far is to use:

```
set Lines=TYPE Z:\archive\%username%.txt | FIND "" /v /c
```

To find the number of lines within the file and use a `Do until i = Lines` to dir each line.

How can I add each line from the .txt file into an array so that I can dir them?  And on top of that how can I output that to a .txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many concepts from other languages that you cannot translate directly into Windows batch.

Batch files do not have any inherent concept of arrays. They can be emulated by clever use of variable names, but that is not needed here.

Also, you cannot simply assign the result of a command to an environment variable like you can in 'nix shells. You can iterate each line of output from a command using something like `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('someCommand') do REM Do something with the line of output contained within %%A`. For example, you could build an "array" of values. But again, there is no need to process the results of a command here, let alone build an array.

The FOR /F command is a complicated beast that can do many things, depending on the syntax used. One of the capabilities is to iterate the lines of a file. So your solution is as simple as:

```
for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%F in ("Z:\archive\%username%.txt") do dir "%%F"
```

If you run the command directly from the console, and not from within a batch script,
then each `%%F` must become `%F`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that; any tips on how to have the results of this outputted to a different (or the same if that's easier) textfile?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this solution :

```dos
@echo off
Title Display recursively all Folders using Array
SET "Count=0"
set "Folder=%userprofile%\Desktop"
set "ListFolders=%~dp0ListFolders.txt"
If Exist %ListFolders% Del %ListFolders%
Dir /b /s /a:d "%folder%" >> %ListFolders%
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Populate the array with existent sub-folders in this folder
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('Type "%ListFolders%"') do (
    set /a Count+=1
    set "Folder[!Count!]=%%~na"
    set "ListpathFolder[!Count!]=%%~fa"
)
::********************************************************
:Display_Folders
cls & color 0B
echo wscript.echo Len("%Folder%"^) + 20 >"%tmp%\length.vbs"
for /f %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\length.vbs"') do ( set "cols=%%a")
If %cols% LSS 50 set /a cols=%cols% + 24
set /a lines=%Count% + 17
Mode con cols=%cols% lines=%lines%
echo(
echo  ------------------------------------------------ 
ECHO   Folder : "%Folder%"
echo  ------------------------------------------------
rem Display array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo [%%i] - "!Folder[%%i]!"
)
echo(
echo Total number in "%Folder%" is %Count%
echo(
echo "Type the number of folder that you want to explore"
set /p "Input="
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    If "%INPUT%" EQU "%%i" (
        Call :Explorer "!ListpathFolder[%%i]!"
        cls
        Dir "!ListpathFolder[%%i]!" 
        echo(
        echo Hit any key to show again all folders ...
        pause>nul
    )
)
Goto Display_Folders
::*********************************************************
:Explorer <file>
explorer.exe /e,/select,"%~1"
Goto :EOF
::*********************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer however this seems to be doing far more than I want; the file I'm reading has file directories simply listed and I want a dir of each of those directories to get some basic information on them outputted to a .txt file